# OpenCart "order again" functionality in the order history

Tags: php, opencart

I am interested in implementing an "order again" function for OpenCart, with a button located in the order history list under `account/order`. This button would take all this particular order's products (and its associated options) and add them all back to the cart.

The following code I have allows me to loop through my product as well as its respective product options depending on the order ID.

```
$products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts(
    $this->request->get['order_id']
);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $options = $this->model_account_order->getOrderOptions(
        $this->request->get['order_id'], 
        $product['order_product_id']
    );

    foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
        // Implement custom logic
    }
}
```

I have no issues at the moment to get the products that I have already ordered. What I do not understand what to do and need help on is - how do I use this [if this is the way to add items to cart] to add the items back to the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon investigation and posting on the OpenCart website, it turns out reorder is already a functionality in OpenCart, but we never enabled it [or someone disabled it months ago]. We had to renable it by adding a button and attributed the `reorder` link under `/catalog/controller/account/order.php`.

We also added some custom logic in our:

```
if ($order_option['type'] == 'select' || $order_option['type'] == 'radio') {
    $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']] = $order_option['product_option_value_id'];
} elseif ($order_option['type'] == 'checkbox') {
    $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']][] = $order_option['product_option_value_id'];
} elseif ($order_option['type'] == 'text' || $order_option['type'] == 'textarea' || $order_option['type'] == 'date' || $order_option['type'] == 'datetime' || $order_option['type'] == 'time') {
    $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']] = $order_option['value'];
} elseif ($order_option['type'] == 'file') {
    $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']] = $this->encryption->encrypt($order_option['value']);
}
```

Since we have a custom option type called `checkbox+quantity`. For the future users, please make sure to add your custom option type logic to this logical statement.

Thanks Jay for pointing this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

By knowing the product ID and quantities (and options if any) you can just call:

```
$this->cart->add($product_id, $quantity, $options); // use array() instead of $options if there are none
```

for each product respectively. `$options` is an array, to see what structure it has to have look into the AJAX request when adding a product with options to the cart (I think it's single array with `product_option_id` as key and `option_value` as value).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$this->cart->add($product_id, $quantity, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually already implemented on the customer side of the cart. Here's the code contained in the `/catalog/controller/account/order.php` that does exactly what you want (1.5.5.1 in this particular case)

```
    if (isset($this->request->get['order_id'])) {
        $order_info = $this->model_account_order->getOrder($this->request->get['order_id']);

        if ($order_info) {
            $order_products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($this->request->get['order_id']);

            foreach ($order_products as $order_product) {
                $option_data = array();

                $order_options = $this->model_account_order->getOrderOptions($this->request->get['order_id'], $order_product['order_product_id']);

                foreach ($order_options as $order_option) {
                    if ($order_option['type'] == 'select' || $order_option['type'] == 'radio') {
                        $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']] = $order_option['product_option_value_id'];
                    } elseif ($order_option['type'] == 'checkbox') {
                        $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']][] = $order_option['product_option_value_id'];
                    } elseif ($order_option['type'] == 'text' || $order_option['type'] == 'textarea' || $order_option['type'] == 'date' || $order_option['type'] == 'datetime' || $order_option['type'] == 'time') {
                        $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']] = $order_option['value'];  
                    } elseif ($order_option['type'] == 'file') {
                        $option_data[$order_option['product_option_id']] = $this->encryption->encrypt($order_option['value']);
                    }
                }

                $this->session->data['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->request->get['order_id']);

                $this->cart->add($order_product['product_id'], $order_product['quantity'], $option_data);
            }

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that last night haha.

Comment: We had to do a little modifications in the `elseif` for option types, since we have a custom `type` called `checkbox+quantity`. But that was trivial to do. Thanks a lot Jay.